# Spring Jpa Service calls vs Jpa query

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am a Spring Jpa beginner. I am having a bug in my mind. I want to know what are the benefits and disadvantages of: 
- Handle all business in Service class and call multiple times to Jpa Repository which contains only basic operation like CRUD, getList ... . 
Vs
- Make a long query `@Query` in Jpa Repository.

Comment: The first one makes no sense. A User already has addresses, and all you need to access them is to call `user.getAddresses()`.  The second doesn't make much sense either. The left join in the query is completely useless. If you want that query to load the user with its addresses in a single query (and not rely on lazy-loading to get the addresses), then the query must be `select distinct u from User u left join fetch u.addresses where u.id = :id`.

Comment: First off, what if it is lazy load? I can not get addresses by calling `user.getAddresses()`.  And why do I need the `distinct ` here? Allways the list is distinct. Skip the example, the question is: is it the same here in my example, I mean the number of times it opens connection to database, the number of queries and proxy accesses.

Comment: Lazy-loading doesn't mean "the addresses won't ever be loaded". It means "the addresses will be loaded when you need them". So yes, calling, for example user.getAddresses().size() will execute an additional query to load the addresses, populate the list of addresses of the user, and then return the number of addresses of the user. The distinct is needed because otherwise, you'll get a List of 3 users if the user has 3 addresses, instead of a list of 1 user.

Comment: _"the addresses will be loaded when you need them"_ thank you, just test it on my machine. "The distinct is needed because otherwise, you'll get a List of 3 users if the user has 3 addresses, instead of a list of 1 user." I thought `User` Onetomany `Address` relation will return a list which `User` contains a list `Address`. Also see my update for modified example

Comment: Without distinct, the query will return one element per row returned by the JDBC query, so you'll get 3 times the same user object (and this user object, repeated 3 times, will have 3 addresses)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I am gonna read these Jpa document carefully.

Comment: What do you think about my modified example?

Comment: Well, you're still ignoring the fact that The user already has addresses, and that setting the addresses on a user is useless. And your query in the second example is worse than the one you got previously: it's not even valid, and doesn't make sense. Re-read my first comment.

Comment: Alright. thank you. I can not make a solid example, but there are situations in my project that I have to choose between "making a long query" and "making many simple queries and handle them in service". So which one should I choose?

Comment: It depends. If the code is easier to read and maintain with the small queries, and fast enough, then use that. Otherwise, use the other.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you would always need to call a single query JPA repository, only to select the objects you need to modify. You may then load data from and modify retrieved objects directly using its methods. The data, which was not loaded by the query, will be loaded automatically when the object needs them.

For example, you may load a person and modify its contact address like this:

```
Person person = personRepository.find(personId);
for (Address address : person.getAddresses()) {
  if ("CONTACT_ADDRESS".equals(address.getType()) {
    address.setCity("London");
  }
}
```

All the necessary data is retrieved and all modifications are persisted to the DB.

Although this is straightforward and easy, sometimes you may have performance issues, especially when you need to load only a single address and not all addresses. Or if you always need all addresses and want to load them in single query together with person.

Then it is a good solution to introduce a new optimized query in the repository. For example, a query, that would load all addresses with a `fetch join` and would not require additional lazy (automatic) query to load them when you iterate through addresses:

```
@Query("select distinct u from User u left join fetch u.addresses where u.id = ?")
public List<User> findWithAddresses(Long id);
```

This would not require to change the above code except to switch method `find()` for `findWithAddresses()`. But there will be only single SQL query executed in background instead of multiple SQL queries.

Comment: Yeah! this is what I am looking for. BTW, do you know when a connection to database is borrowed from connection pool? When it will release the connection?

Comment: Connection is typically assigned during transaction, so it is "borrowed" at transaction start and released at commit or rollback. But I am not sure as this is implementation specific, and it is possible that entitymanager holds the assigned connection until closed, but this would be rather dumb.